# How to generate React Native's Android jni libaries

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk, java-native-interface

React Native on Android has some C/C++ code that gets compiled to .so files. How can I build those .so files? I think it has something to do with https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/Application.mk.

I tried creating a new React Native project and running the following from the project root:

```
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/ndk-build
```

But I get an error:

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk
```

Comment: Try `ndk-build -C node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main`

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: For more official instructions, you can just follow the steps in the React Native docs for [building from source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html). Building from source will run the [buildReactNdkLib](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L199) Gradle task which builds those .so files.

---

I figured out how to generate these .so files:

1. In the React Native source code I found this [build.gradle file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L199) that has a `buildReactNdkLib` task.
2. I captured the command it runs, which in my case was:

   ```
   ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null NDK_APPLICATION_MK=~/.../react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/Application.mk NDK_OUT=~/.../react-native/ReactAndroid/build/tmp/buildReactNdkLib NDK_LIBS_OUT=~/.../react-native/ReactAndroid/build/react-ndk/all THIRD_PARTY_NDK_DIR=~/.../react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk REACT_COMMON_DIR=~/.../react-native/ReactAndroid/../ReactCommon -C ~/.../react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/jni --jobs 4
   ```
3. Replace `~/.../react-native` in command above with path to react-native repo.
4. As is I was getting errors like `Android NDK: Module reactnativejni depends on undefined modules: fbjni` and `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: Command not found`. To fix I had to switch to an older version of NDK:

   1. Download and extract Android NDK, Revision 10e (May 2015) from [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html).
   2. Change path `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build` in command above to the extracted folder's `ndk-build` file.
5. The generated .so files will be in `react-native/ReactAndroid/build/react-ndk/all`.